# RichFaces 4 generating incorrect links for image resources

Tags: richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4.1 final in a portal environment (IBM Websphere Portal) using IBM portlet bridge.

For some of the image resources richfaces seems to be generating incorrect links. For examples a image resource generated looks like

/rfRes/**gradientA.png.jsf.jsf**?v=4.1.0.Final&db=eAFjZJBjZDBiZBBh!H8!IoLx!wQGBgYmACkLBIk_&ln=org.richfaces.images

As you can see ".jsf" is appended twice to the image resource. These seems to happen only with a image resource. Other links for css for js files seem to fine. If I remove one of the .jsf appended then the resource is server fine.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a work-around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a temporary workaround for this issue using "org.richfaces.resourceMapping.enabled" property. Set this property to 'true' within web.xml and Within the custom-mapping properties file, point the url's to your own library of image files.